# URLWithString: returns nil even when constructed with a correct URL

Tags: ios, nsurl

I'm trying to build a NSURL from a string like this :

```
NSString *urlString = self.providerData[@"LogoUrl"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSLog(@"logo url string : %@ - logo url : %@", urlString, url);
```

Here's the output :

```
logo url string :  http://cdn.site-annonce.fr/img/mobile/multipublish/TopAnnonces.png - logo url : (null)
```

The doc says it can return nil if the URL is malformed. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the output literally, there's leading whitespace (two blanks) even though the format string contains only one.

Fix with :

```
urlString = [urlString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: jeez! I really missed it

Answer (score 1):

When you copy & paste the log results and the source code, you have a leading space in your URL.